# Convergence to a 2-dimensional vector of independent exponential variables

Tags: statistics, asymptotics

Let $Y_{n(1)}$ and $Y_{n(n)}$ be the minimum and maximum of a random sample $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n$ from the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.
The sequence $(n(Y_{n(1)}),n(1-Y_{n(n)})$ converges in distribution to $(U,V)$ where $U$ and $V$ are independent exponential variables.

To show this, I started with 
\begin{align}
P(nY_{n(1)}\leq x, n(1-Y_{n(n)})\leq y)\\
= P(Y_{n(1)}\leq \frac{x}{n}, (1-Y_{n(n)})\leq \frac{y}{n})\\
= P(Y_{n(1)}\leq \frac{x}{n} | Y_{n(n)}\geq \frac{-y}{n}+1)P(Y_{n(n)}\geq \frac{-y}{n}+1)
\end{align}

I'm sure that $Y_{n(1)}$ and $Y_{n(n)}$ are not independent and I know that
\begin{align}
P(Y_{n(n)}\geq \frac{-y}{n}+1)\rightarrow 1-e^{-y}
\end{align}

Then the conditional one, I thought about integrals but then also the density of $Y_{n(n)}$ is needed. And of course $\frac{-y}{n}+1\rightarrow 1$ but then it would be a too large step (I think) to conclude that the conditional one is simply converging to $1-e^{-x}$, by which the proof would be done.

Is there anyone who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking the right approach, but it becomes much easier if you instead consider 
 $$\mathbb P(n Y_{n(1)} \ge x, n(1 - Y_{n(n)}) \ge y),$$
because this is true if and only if $\frac xn \le Y_i \le 1 - \frac yn$ for all $i$. This has probability $\left(1 - \frac{x+y}{n}\right)^n$, and $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{x+y}{n}\right)^n = e^{-(x+y)} = e^{-x} e^{-y}.$$
From here, things are straightforward, because this matches $\mathbb P(U \ge x, V \ge y)$ if $U$ and $V$ are independent exponential variables with rate $1$.

In general, when dealing with exponential distribution, the tail distribution function $\mathbb P(X \ge x)$ is much easier to deal with than the ordinary cdf, and here is no exception.

Comment: Then we are left with considering $P(nY_{n(1)}<x, n(1-Y_{n(n)})\geq y)$ and $P(nY_{n(1)}\geq x, n(1-Y_{n(n)})<y)$ because the definition of a CDF is that the two "$\geq$" become "$\leq$". Or is there a theorem that states that we are not left with them?

Comment: I don't see why you want to consider them, but you can derive them from the above easily: setting $y=0$ tells us $\mathbb P(n Y_{n(1)} \ge x) \to e^{-x}$, and then we can write $\mathbb P(n Y_{n(1)} \ge x, n(1 - Y_{n(n)}) < y)$ as $$\mathbb P(n Y_{n(1)} \ge x) - \mathbb P(n Y_{n(1)} \ge x, n(1 - Y_{n(n)}) \ge y).$$

Comment: Oh yes, it's easy. I thought it would be difficult because $Y_{n(1)}$ and $Y_{n(n)}$ are dependent. I want to consider them because a CDF is not $P(X > x, Y > y)$. If that is calculated, then we are left with the two others in order to get $P(X \leq x, Y \leq y)$.